# Recursive method in Java that calculates factorials not working

Tags: java, math, methods, recursion, factorial

Coding a recursive method in Java that calculates factorials. Unfortunately it's not working, and I suspect it's because of the 2 parameters that I wasn't too sure about -- which I surrounded with asterisks. Are those the correct parameters that belong there? Or do I need to change them to something else and why?

```
public fact(n)
{
   return this.factHelp(n, ***n+1*** );
}

private factHelp(n, result)
{
   if (n == 0)
      return result;
   else
      return this.factHelp(n – 1, ***result***);
}
```

Comment: Why don't you debug it and find out?

Comment: @user2777815 man did invent print statements

Comment: Think about what you're doing. When do you have change result? You just keep passing it back. Something has to happen to result/

Comment: @Cruncher I'm fairly new to programming. Not too sure how to use print statements to debug..

Comment: @Cruncher makes sense a bit. Do I have to keep subtracting 1 from result?

Comment: @user2777815 Think about it in your head. Step through the execution of the program on paper, subtracting 1.

Comment: The program I'm using to run my code doesn't mind the syntax errors. So I know for sure that it's not anything to do with that. Thanks though @user2246674

Comment: @user2777815 are you sure it's java? That is definately not valid java code.

Comment: @Cruncher It's sort of like a pseudo-java-code thing, I guess. I'm thinking -- shouldn't there be some sort of multiplication involved here somewhere? Like n * n - 1?

Comment: @user2777815 well, the end result you want is 1 * 2 * 3 * 4 * ... * n so you need to do some multiplying somewhere.

Comment: @Cruncher But where? I've been pondering this for so long i'm going crazy hahaha

Comment: @user2777815 try 1 in the first one, and n*result in the second. Once you understand this, maybe you can answer your own question

Comment: @Cruncher You were right. It worked. Time to study/understand this. THanks!

Answer (score 2):

This code doesn't compile.

1. You're missing the return types on both of these methods.  You should use `public int fact...` instead of `public fact...`
2. Your parameters don't have types.  It should probably be `fact(int n)` instead of `fact(n)`
3. You don't *need* two functions to do this.  You can use two if you want, but I just wanted to let you know it's unnecessary.
4. You should probably google for "recursive factorial algorithm" to get more help.

Comment: I've never heard of the phrase "TCO variant" and the person who asked the question probably hasn't either.  Can you elaborate further?

Comment: It makes it easier to setup the initial call condition (from the external code).

Comment: I was wrong about that. This is written as such (vs. adding to the return of the method). However, see previous comment - I think this is where using two methods is better here as it hides the internals.

Comment: @user2246674 frankly, in a real word scenario, I would just use iteration. Why use stack space?

Comment: @Cruncher because "don't preoptimize".

Comment: @tieTYT What you say makes sense, but the program I'm running it on interprets it as some sort of pseudo-Java-code and doesn't mind the missing return types. Would you know what may be wrong with my parameters off the top of your head? Thanks!

Comment: @tieTYT the iterative formula is: easier to understand, less code, faster, uses less memory. I see no reason to use the recursive version.

Comment: @Cruncher "easier to understand" is subjective.  I may be biased because I've been learning a lot about functional programming lately, but I actually think the recursive algorithm is easier to understand and therefore the most maintainable.  Relative to maintainability, all the other points come last.

Comment: @user2777815 sorry I won't be able to help.  I can help you with java, but not some java-ish language.  I only know the syntax of languages I know :)

Comment: @tieTYT `I only know the syntax of the languages I know` That tautology ;). Also, I guess we can't argue over something subjective. But I think we can agree that the iterative option is accessible to more people. I'd bet OP could write the iterative function.

Comment: @Cruncher yeah that I agree with